# How to filter data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have done pairwise comparison between some data and my output is as below, Now I like to filter  and keep comparison with value lower than 0.02.

```
     d1      d2        d3      d4  
d1   NA      0.033   0.323    0.008
d2   NA      NA      0.039    0.056
d3   NA      NA       NA      0.004
d4   NA      NA       NA       NA
```

I like to have

```
d1-d4  0.008
d3-d4  0.004
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base` R

```
vals <- na.omit(unlist(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[x < 0.02])))
as.data.frame(vals)
#       vals
#d1.d4 0.008
#d3.d4 0.004
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do (your data is saved in `d`):

```
# find the row and column index with smaller values
gr <- which(d<0.02, arr.ind = T)
# get the row and col names and paste them together
a1 <- paste(rownames(d)[ gr[, 1]], colnames(d)[ gr[, 2]], sep="-")
# subset the values
a2 <- d[gr]
# and the result
data.frame(a1, a2)

     a1    a2
1 d1-d4 0.008
2 d3-d4 0.004
```